# Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants from extended 3d TQFTs

Tags: knot-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, cobordism, braided-tensor-categories

Attached to any object $V\in \mathcal{C}$ of a ribbon category $\mathcal{C}$, Reshetikhin and Turaev have defined knot invariants
$$\tau_V(K)\ \in\ \text{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(1_{\mathcal{C}})$$
for instance see Turaev's ["Quantum Invariants of Knots and 3-Manifolds"](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110435221/html?lang=en). In examples this is often just a complex number or element of some ring. The argument is something like

1. There is (?) a unique functor $F:\text{Rib}\to \mathcal{C}$ of
   ribbon categories, where $\text{Rib}$ is the category of oriented
   0-manifolds with morphisms the framed cobordisms between them, such
   that $F(+)=V$.

(As stated in the reference we need to use a bigger category than $\text{Rib}$ including coupons etc., but that's not needed for knot invariants and so one might hope that the simplified version I wrote above is true, if it's not true then in my question just replace $\text{Rib}$ with that larger category). Then,

2. View a (framed) knot $K\subseteq S^3$ as a (framed) cobordism
   $K:\varnothing\to \varnothing$, then we get $F(K):1_\mathcal{C}\to
   1_\mathcal{C}$, which is our invariant.

---

My **question** is then: say there is a fully extended 3d TQFT $\mathcal{T}$ such that
$$\mathcal{T}(S^1)\ =\ \mathcal{C}.$$
Does the functor $F:\text{Rib}\to \mathcal{C}$, hence the knot invariant, have a simple description in terms of $\mathcal{T}$? I assume the answer is yes, but I haven't been able to come up with it.